# different structs reusing same method

Tags: go, inheritance, struct, embedding

Below is simplified Go code.

As you can see, it wrote twice `String()`, is there any way to write just once?

```
type A struct {
    Name   string
}
func (u A) String() string {
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")

    return fmt.Sprintf("A:\n" + string(out))
}

type B struct {
    Name   string
}
func (u B) String() string {
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")

    return fmt.Sprintf("B:\n" + string(out))
}
```

Something like to implement a `struct Base`, which has a method `did()`,

then `struct A` and `struct B` implement `struct Base`, so they can call `did()` without need to implement `did()` itself again.

==============

Edited:

The previous sample code is not very clear, now I changed it.

The `struct A` and `struct B` have different fields, and how can we write `String()` just once, then apply to two structs?

```
type A struct {
    Name     string
    Status   string
}
func (u A) String() string {
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")
    return fmt.Sprintf("A:\n" + string(out))
}

type B struct {
    ID   int
    Logo   string
}
func (u B) String() string {
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")
    return fmt.Sprintf("B:\n" + string(out))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to write just once?

**TL;DR** Probably not.

In your exact example, there are two approaches that will work, but neither is very useful in real code, and I expect neither will address your actual need.

1. The most obvious is to have just a single type, since they're identical anyway. Or make your second type a copy of the first:

   ```golang
   type A struct {
       Name   string
   }
   func (u A) String() string {
       out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")

       return fmt.Sprintf("A:\n" + string(out))
   }

   type B A
   ```
2. You can use struct embedding. This works because your structs contain exactly the same fields, so they can both embed a common struct:

   ```golang
   type common struct  {
       Name string
   }

   func (u common) String() string {
       out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")
       return fmt.Sprintf("A:\n" + string(out))
   }

   type A struct {
       common
   }

   type B struct {
       common
   }
   ```

However, I expect your two structs also contain more fields that are not shared. Which means that both of these approaches won't work.  As in example 2, you *can* embed a struct with the common values, but then your `String()` method will *only have access to the common fields*. See an example [in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NGW6bjS3qQZ)

A final approach, which might apply to you, but absolutely will not apply in all cases, is to write a custom `String()` method on each of the outer types, which in turn calls an embedded `String()` function to calculate the common part. Whether this works for you or not, of course, depends a lot on what format you want.  I discuss a similar approach for JSON marshaling with embedded structs [on my blog](https://jhall.io/posts/go-json-tricks-embedded-marshaler/), and in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599230/13860).  Since your `String()` method is actually producing JSON, it may apply to you, as well.

It might look something like this:

```golang
type common struct  {
    Name string
}

func (u common) String() string {
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")
    return fmt.Sprintf("A:\n" + string(out))
}

type A struct {
    common
    Age int
}

func (u A) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s Age: %d", u.common.String(), u.Age)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this in Go. But it may or may not work depending on your exact use case. You can use an [embedded struct](https://go101.org/article/type-embedding.html).

That would look like this:

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PG2J_1SU4XM)

```
type Stringer struct {
   Name string
}

func (u Stringer) String() string {
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "\t")

    return fmt.Sprintf(string(out))
}

type A struct {
   Stringer
}

type B struct {
   Stringer
}
```

Note that any fields which are in `A` or `B` but not in Stringer will not be included in the result of `String() string`. Thus this may not work for your case if you require any such fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a embedded struct like so which implements the `String` method

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    embd
}

type B struct {
    embd
}

type embd struct {
    Name string
    typ  string
}

func (e embd) String() string {
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(e, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf(e.typ + ":\n" + string(out))
}

func main() {
    a := A{embd{"Foo", "A"}}
    fmt.Println(a.String())

    b := B{embd{"Bar", "B"}}
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}
```