# How to marshal an embedded struct in go?

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I've come across a case which is new to me in go. I think it is something similar to this question [Idiomatic way to embed struct with custom MarshalJSON() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489776/idiomatic-way-to-embed-struct-with-custom-marshaljson-method)

Here is an example of code that I am trying to apply

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {

    icpPath, _ := os.LookupEnv("GETH_ICP_PATH")
    
    client, _ := ethclient.Dial(icpPath)
    ctx := context.Background()

    header, _ := client.HeaderByNumber(ctx, nil)
    data, _ := header.MarshalJSON()

    fmt.Println(string(data))

}
```

**output**

```json
{"parentHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347","miner":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","stateRoot":"0xd7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544","transactionsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","receiptsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","difficulty":"0x400000000","number":"0x0","gasLimit":"0x1388","gasUsed":"0x0","timestamp":"0x0","extraData":"0x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1c8370e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa","mixHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","nonce":"0x0000000000000042","baseFeePerGas":null,"hash":"0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"}
```

In this output for example the field `"difficulty"`  has a value of `"0x400000000"`

I can marshal this field like this:

```golang
difficulty, _ := header.Difficulty.MarshalJSON()
fmt.Println(string(difficulty))
```

and get the following output

```
17179869184
```

---

the type of `header` is as defined here
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go

```golang
// Header represents a block header in the Ethereum blockchain.
type Header struct {
    ParentHash  common.Hash    `json:"parentHash"       gencodec:"required"`
    UncleHash   common.Hash    `json:"sha3Uncles"       gencodec:"required"`
    Coinbase    common.Address `json:"miner"            gencodec:"required"`
    Root        common.Hash    `json:"stateRoot"        gencodec:"required"`
    TxHash      common.Hash    `json:"transactionsRoot" gencodec:"required"`
    ReceiptHash common.Hash    `json:"receiptsRoot"     gencodec:"required"`
    Bloom       Bloom          `json:"logsBloom"        gencodec:"required"`
    Difficulty  *big.Int       `json:"difficulty"       gencodec:"required"`
    Number      *big.Int       `json:"number"           gencodec:"required"`
    GasLimit    uint64         `json:"gasLimit"         gencodec:"required"`
    GasUsed     uint64         `json:"gasUsed"          gencodec:"required"`
    Time        uint64         `json:"timestamp"        gencodec:"required"`
    Extra       []byte         `json:"extraData"        gencodec:"required"`
    MixDigest   common.Hash    `json:"mixHash"`
    Nonce       BlockNonce     `json:"nonce"`

    // BaseFee was added by EIP-1559 and is ignored in legacy headers.
    BaseFee *big.Int `json:"baseFeePerGas" rlp:"optional"`
}
```

---

My question is:

What is the right way to get the json output completly marshaled without going in iterative way through all fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `types.Header` type implements a custom json marshaler [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5cff9754d795971451f2f4e8a2cc0c6f51ce9802/core/types/gen_header_json.go#L17-L56), and as you can see it replaces `Difficulty *big.Int` with `Difficulty *hexutil.Big` which is why you get that hex value in the json.

To disable the custom marshaler you can declare a new type using `types.Header` as the [*type definition*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions), and then, just before you marshal the header, you convert it to this new type.

```golang
h := types.Header{Difficulty: big.NewInt(17179869184)}

type MyHeader types.Header // declare new type
out, err := json.Marshal(MyHeader(h)) // convert & marshal
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8CtWWDeItbO